# Match buffer size to window size

Tags: c#, windows, console

This code makes the console window borderless and fullsize:

```
public static Coord InitializeConsole(nint consoleHandle, nint stdOutput, in int fontWidth, in int fontHeight, ColorPalette colorPalette)
{
    var consoleRect = new RECT();
    GetWindowRect(consoleHandle, ref consoleRect);

    var desktopWidth = GetSystemMetrics(0);
    var desktopHeight = GetSystemMetrics(1);

    _ = SetWindowLong(consoleHandle, -16, 0x00080000);

    var csbe = new CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX();
    csbe.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(csbe);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOutput, ref csbe);

    SetColorPalette(stdOutput, colorPalette, ref csbe);

    csbe.dwSize.X = (short)(desktopWidth / fontWidth);
    csbe.dwSize.Y = (short)(desktopHeight / fontHeight);
    ++csbe.srWindow.Bottom;
    ++csbe.srWindow.Right;

    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOutput, ref csbe);

    SetWindowPos(
        consoleHandle,
        nint.Zero,
        0, 0,
        windowWidth,
        windowHeight,
        0x0040);
    
    DrawMenuBar(consoleHandle);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOutput, ref csbe);

    return new(csbe.dwSize.X, csbe.dwSize.Y);
}
```

My problem is that on some font heights the console buffer is too big for the console window and the scrollbar appears.

**How can I set the Buffer size that the scrollbar never appears?**

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Coord InitializeConsole(nint consoleHandle, nint stdOutput, in int fontWidth, in int fontHeight, ColorPalette colorPalette)
{
    var consoleRect = new RECT();
    GetWindowRect(consoleHandle, ref consoleRect);

    var desktopWidth = GetSystemMetrics(0);
    var desktopHeight = GetSystemMetrics(1);

    _ = SetWindowLong(consoleHandle, -16, 0x00080000);

    var csbe = new CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO_EX();
    csbe.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(csbe);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOutput, ref csbe);

    SetColorPalette(stdOutput, colorPalette, ref csbe);

    csbe.dwSize.X = 1;
    csbe.dwSize.Y = 1;
    ++csbe.srWindow.Bottom;
    ++csbe.srWindow.Right;

    SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOutput, ref csbe);

    SetWindowPos(
        consoleHandle,
        nint.Zero,
        0, 0,
        windowWidth,
        windowHeight,
        0x0040);
    
    DrawMenuBar(consoleHandle);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx(stdOutput, ref csbe);

    return new(csbe.dwSize.X, csbe.dwSize.Y);
}
```

Fixed it by setting the Buffer Height and Width to 1.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).